Dehn-twist on punctured 3-manifold
What I aim to understand is under what circumstances the Dehn twist along the boundary 2-sphere of a punctured 3-manifold $M' = M \setminus \text{int}(B^3)$ results in a non-trivial element of the mapping class group (rel boundary).
The interpretation of a Dehn twist here is as follows: analogous to the case of surfaces, consider a non-trivial loop of diffeomorphisms of $S^2$ (noting that $\pi_1(\text{Diff}(S^2)) = \mathbb{Z}_2$). Then, construct a self-diffeomorphism of $S^2 \times I$ by unwrapping the loop. Since the induced diffeomorphism is the identity on the boundary, it can be extended to $M'$ as the identity on outside a collar neighborhood of the boundary $S^2$.
I am particularly interested in understanding for which 3-manifolds this Dehn twist is trivial or non-trivial. One observation is that in some cases, if $M'$ admits a well-behaved circle action, the Dehn twist is trivial (e.g., $M= S^3$). However, I am struggling to construct an argument for $T^3$ or $S^1 \times S^2$.
It would be highly appreciated if someone could provide insights or an approach. [I attempted to adapt a proof similar to the one showing why boundary Dehn twists are non-trivial for surfaces with boundary but have not succeeded.]

In case this is of use to you: Dehn twists of connected sums and of products of manifolds in any dimension can be expressed in terms of the Dehn twists of their summands/factors, see for instance Proposition 1.1 of https://doi.org/10.1090/btran/207 . This implies for example that it is trivial for any product with $S^2$.  A proof that the Dehn twist is nontrivial for manifolds homotopy equivalent to tori can be found in Corollary 1.2 of the same paper. For the standard torus there are surely much earlier references.

@archipelago Thanks for the reference. Seems like very helpful!!

I'm not sure this is known in complete generality.  Let me give you two references that have discussions of what is known.  The first is Remark 2.4 in the following paper:
A. Hatcher and N. Wahl, Stabilization for mapping class groups of 3-manifolds, Duke Math. J. 155 (2010), no. 2, 205–269.
The second is the discussion at the end of the introduction to my paper
T. Brendle, N. Broaddus, and A. Putman, The mapping class group of connect sums of $S^2 \times S^1$, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 376 (2023), 2557-2572.
One interesting example is $M$ equal to a sphere with $k$ open disks removed.  In that case, the mapping class group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^{k-1}$, generated by the sphere twists about the boundary components.  The $k-1$ appears since the product of those twists is trivial.  See Remark 2.6 of my paper for more on this.
One final subtle point: whether or not sphere twists about separating spheres are trivial can depend on whether you define the mapping class group as the group of homotopy classes of maps or isotopy classes of maps.  The discussion at the end of the intro to my paper discusses this and gives references.

Thank you for the answer.

I take it you consider the mapping class group to be the isotopy classes of diffeomorphisms that are the identity on the boundary?
I think you can give a fairly complete answer to this problem with existing tools.
The main thing is to consider the bundle
$$ Diff(M') \to Diff(M) \to Emb(D^3, M) $$
If $M$ is orientable and $\partial M \neq \emptyset$ then the dehn twist about the boundary sphere is non-trivial in $\pi_0 Diff(M')$.
The idea is that $Emb(D^3, M) \simeq O_3 \times M$ and the Dehn twist corresponds to the generator of $\pi_1 O_3$ under the connecting map.  The fact that $\partial M \neq \emptyset$ implies that the bundle projection map $Diff(M) \to Emb(D^3, M)$ is null-homotopic, thus the Dehn twist is non-trivial in $\pi_0 Diff(M')$.
So in general your question amounts to whether or not $\pi_1 Diff(M) \to \pi_1 Emb(D^3, M)$ hits the generator of $\pi_1 O_3 \simeq \mathbb Z_2$.
I think the answer is yes for $S^3$, $\mathbb RP^3$, $S^1 \times S^2$, $\mathbb RP^3 \# \mathbb RP^3$, but then no for most other manifolds: I think all other geometric manifolds and then no for manifolds with incompressible tori and non-prime manifolds.  These last two steps require chasing the homotopy long exact sequences of the fibrations for the associated diffeomorphism groups.  There ?might? be some cases I'm missing but this technique will certainly get you to an answer, and I doubt the list is much longer than the one I've assembled above.

This is what Hatcher-Wahl do in the Remark 2.4 I referred to in my answer.  They indicate there that we don’t know the answer in all cases.

Thanks to both Ryan and Andy, yes I care about everything relative to the boundary here.
